# Whenever I use strftime() in filename with the csv module my data doesn't get written to the .csv file

Tags: python, csv, datetime, timestamp, strftime

I have run into a problem with trying to timestamp a filename with strftime()

Here is the code :

```
from urllib.request import urlopen as uReq
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as souce
import csv
import datetime


csv_file_stamped='prices_checked-'+time.strftime("%Y-%m-%d-%H:%M")+'.csv'
print(csv_file_stamped)
csv_file_new=open(csv_file_stamped,'w')
csv_writer=csv.writer(csv_file_new)
csv_writer.writerow(["Item_Link","Item_Price"])

csv_file=open('scraped_from_ebay.csv','r')
csv_reader=csv.DictReader(csv_file)
data=list(csv_reader)
links=len(data)
print("Total number of links to be checked: "+str(links)+"\n")
csv_file2=open('scraped_from_ebay.csv','r')
csv_reader2=csv.DictReader(csv_file2)

for line in csv_reader2:
    uClient=uReq(line['Item_link'])
    page_html=uClient.read()
    uClient.close()
    page_soup=souce(page_html, "html.parser")
    price_dirty=page_soup.find("span",{"class":"notranslate"})
    price_clean=price_dirty.get_text().replace("EUR ","")
    csv_writer.writerow([line['Item_link'],price_clean])
```

The funny thing is that I get a blank file without any extension and no data in the file. If I use `csv_file_new=open('whatevername.csv','w')` it works just fine. The data gets written into the file and the file has the right name and extension. However when I print the csv_file_stamped I get exactly the wanted filename. 
Any idea what might be causing the problem ?
Thanks in advance

Comment: as your code is not working (time is not defined, no samples from 'scraped_from_ebay.csv') wa can't help you. but even if it did, nothing in it would explain the behavior you're describing. so the problem lies where you really generate the file name

Answer (score 0):

Figured it out!

```
csv_file_stamped=str('prices_checked-'+time.strftime("%Y-%m-%d-%H:%M")+'.csv')
```

I am using " **:** " as a separator for the seconds and it's a no go with a filename in windows :)